# Avoid duplicate elements when scraping a page with infinite scroll

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to scrape this site.

https://www.foodpanda.sg/restaurants/new?lat=1.2915902&lng=103.8379066&vertical=restaurants

for restaurant details.

I need to scroll down to get more restaurants. How to avoid duplicates when new elements are loaded?. As of now it loads the new elements but in the csv most of them are duplicates. I tried something like this which works on other site..but it didn't work out on this.

```
        current_len = len(likes_div.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="q9uorilb"]//a'))
        while True:
            likes_div.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="q9uorilb"]//a').send_keys(Keys.END)
            try:
                WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
                    lambda x: len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="q9uorilb"]//a')) > current_len)
                current_len = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="q9uorilb"]//a'))
            except TimeoutException:
                name_eles = [name_ele for name_ele in
                             driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="q9uorilb"]//a')]
```

This is my code for the web page above.

```
def get_rest():

    time.sleep(15)
    restaurant_locator = '//ul[@class="vendor-list"]//li[@data-testid and not(@class)]'
    restaurants = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(restaurant_locator)
    return restaurants



def get_data(rests):
    global header_added
    for rest in rests:
        try:
            name = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="name fn"]').text
        except:
            name = 'No name'
        print(name)
        print('*********')
        try:
            link_a = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//a')
            link = link_a.get_attribute('href')
        except:
            link = 'No link available'
        print(link)
        print('**********')
        try:
            rating = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="rating"]').text
            rating = rating[:-2]

        except:
            rating = 'No Ratings Available'
        print(rating)
        print('*********')
        try:
            cuisine = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//ul[@class="categories summary"]').text
            cuisine = cuisine[4:]
        except:
            cuisine = 'Cuisine Details Not Available'
        print(cuisine)
        print('***********')
        try:
            distance = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="badge-info"]').text
        except:
            distance = "No Distance available"
        print(distance)
        print('***********')
        try:
            tags = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="tag-container"]').text
        except:
            tags = "No special Offers"
        print(tags)
        print('************')
        try:
            cashback = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="vendor-cashback-info"]').text
        except:
            cashback = "No Cashback available"
        print(cashback)

        dict1 = {'Restaurant Name': name, "Rating": rating, "Cuisine": cuisine, "Delivery Time": distance,
                 "Tags": tags, "Cashback": cashback}
        with open(f'Food_Panda_test.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
            if not header_added:
                w.writeheader()
                header_added = True
            w.writerow(dict1)


while True:
    p = get_rest()
    get_data(p)
```

Comment: Did you try using requests module? You could get all the restaurant names within 2/3 minutes exhausting linfinite scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think removing of duplicates should be done once you have restaurant details :

Let's say you have a list `restaurants` with duplicates.

Remove duplicates entry like this :

```
seen = set(restaurants)
if item not in seen:
    seen.add(item)
    restaurants.append(item)
```

if you have multiple list then make a generic function and pass list to get the job done.

**Update 1:**

When you are doing this `p = get_rest()` then p is a list.

do this :

```
seen = set(p)
    if item not in seen:
        seen.add(item)
        p.append(item)
```

Now all **duplicates** will get removed.

and then do

```
 get_data(p)
```

Comment: @AbhishekRai : Check out the updated code 1

Comment: `item ` represent single or individual entity in a list.

Comment: I can not run your code right now, will let you know once I will be able to

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the idea given by @cruisepandey. Thanks

```
old_rest = set()  #Empty Set
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,3825)", "")
    time.sleep(15)
    restaurant_locator = '//ul[@class="vendor-list"]//li[@data-testid and not(@class)]'
    restaurants = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(restaurant_locator) #Find Elements
    ans = set(restaurants) - set(old_rest) #Remove old elements


    for rest in ans:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", rest)
        try:
            name = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="name fn"]').text
        except:
            name = 'No name'
        print(name)
        print('*********')
        try:
            link_a = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//a')
            link = link_a.get_attribute('href')
        except:
            link = 'No link available'
        print(link)
        print('**********')
        try:
            rating = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="rating"]').text
            rating = rating[:-2]

        except:
            rating = 'No Ratings Available'
        print(rating)
        print('*********')
        try:
            cuisine = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//ul[@class="categories summary"]').text
            cuisine = cuisine[4:]
        except:
            cuisine = 'Cuisine Details Not Available'
        print(cuisine)
        print('***********')
        try:
            distance = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="badge-info"]').text
        except:
            distance = "No Distance available"
        print(distance)
        print('***********')
        try:
            tags = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[@class="tag-container"]').text
        except:
            tags = "No special Offers"
        print(tags)
        print('************')
        try:
            cashback = rest.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="vendor-cashback-info"]').text
        except:
            cashback = "No Cashback available"
        print(cashback)

        dict1 = {'Restaurant Name': name, "URL":link, "Rating": rating, "Cuisine": cuisine, "Delivery Time": distance,
                 "Tags": tags, "Cashback": cashback}
        with open(f'Food_Panda_test.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
            if not header_added:
                w.writeheader()
                header_added = True
            w.writerow(dict1)
        old_rest = restaurants #assign scraped items to old_rest
```